# Write a program that will display all prime numbers from the given range

Tags: c++, oop, parameters

Write a program that will display all prime numbers from the given range. The program must satisfy the following requirements:
a. ask the user of range to display
b. contains the following function:
i. checkRange() – a functions that checks if the entered range is correct or not. A message will be displayed if the range is invalid.
ii. displayPrime() – a function that displays all prime numbers in the given range
NOTE: you will provide the parameter(s) for each function.

**here's the code that i made: there is something wrong in my code. I can't pinpoint what is it**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    int Prime, strt, end, result;
    bool isprime=true;
    
    Again:
    cout<<"Start: ";
    cin>>strt;
    
    cout<<"End: ";
    cin>>strt;
    
    cout<<"\n";
    if (strt>end)
    {
        cout<<"Range is Invalid, Try Again."<<"\n";
        goto Again;
    }
    result = Prime(strt,end);
    cout<<"Prime numbers in the given range are: "<<result<<endl;
    return 0;
}

int Prime(int strt, int end, int num, isprime)
{
    int result;
    while (strt<end)
    {
        isprime=true;
        if (strt == 0 || strt == 1) 
        {
            isprime = false;
        }
    for (num = 2; num <= strt/2; ++num) 
    {
      if (strt % num == 0) 
      {
        isprime = false;
        break;
      }
    }
        
    if (isprime)
      cout << strt << ", ";
    ++strt;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: `int Prime(int strt, int end, int num, isprime)` is used before it is declared.

Comment: You also declared a local variable named `Prime` which you never use, making this even more confusing

Comment: _there is something wrong in my code. I can't pinpoint what is it_ -> But you can describe the behaviour that you get: Do you get any errors? Do you get an unexpected/empty/wrong output? Please add some more details!

Comment: If you don't use sieve, then create a function `bool isPrime(int)` that you can test by itself.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer, there are many issues with the code that I won't go through them, ask if you don't understand something

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int prime(int strt, int end)
{
    bool isprime;
    int count;
    while (strt<end)
    {
        isprime=true;
        if (strt == 0 || strt == 1)
        {
            isprime = false;
        }
        for (int num = 2; num <= strt/2; ++num)
        {
            if (strt % num == 0)
            {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isprime) {
            cout << strt << ", ";
            ++count;
        }
        ++strt;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int strt, end, result;

    Again:
    cout<<"Start: ";
    cin>>strt;

    cout<<"End: ";
    cin>>end;

    cout<<"\n";
    if (strt>end)
    {
        cout<<"Range is Invalid, Try Again."<<"\n";
        goto Again;
    }
    cout<<"Prime numbers in the given range are: ";
    prime(strt,end);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I just started contributing today, and you are making me want to stop ahahahaha

Comment: The harshness isn't directed at you personally, it's a comment on the content, I don't mean to make you want to leave. The criticism being the point of an exercise is not just to have an answer but to learn. Handing the OP the answer defeats the exercise.

Comment: well, I don't see you explaining our friend the differences between initializing and declaring, or teaching him, and I didn't gave him the answer I just fixed his code it's not like I wrote him a sieve or something, I'm sure him having that code is better than no answers at all

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255019/4832499).

Answer (score -1):

This is Probably the simplest way I can put it for you.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int check_range(int a,int b)
{
    if (a > b)
    return 0;
    else 
    return 1;
}

int check_prime(int a,int b)
{
    bool isprime;
    while (a < b)
    {
        isprime=true;
        if (a == 0 || a == 1)
        {
            isprime = false;
        }
        for (int i = 2; i <= a/2; i++)
        {
            if (a % i == 0)
            {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (isprime) {
            cout <<a<<" ";
        }
        a++;
    }
        
}

int main()
{   
    int strt,end;
    
    Repeat :
        
    cout<<"Enter the lower limit of range :";
    cin>>strt;
    cout<<"Enter the upper limit of range :";
    cin>>end;
    
    int p = check_range(strt,end);
    
    if (p)
    {
        check_prime(strt,end);
    } 
    else 
    {
        cout<<"The range is inappropriate.\n";
        goto Repeat;
    }
}
```

Hope you would understand.